# How to assign a hidden value to a combobox list item? NameValuePair?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to switch my application over from VBA-excel to .net and I'm new at both! I'm trying to figure out how to have a number value associated with a text value shown in my combobox. For an example: combobox shows fabric names and I need a number value with the fluid volume of the thickness of that type of fabric. I've been reading up on NameValuePair but I'm having a hard time applying it.

Here is how my combobox is configured.

```
 Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.ComboBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.ComboBox2 = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Button2 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'ComboBox1
    '
    Me.ComboBox1.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(New Object() {"Carbon Fiber Twill", "Carbon Fiber Plain"})
    Me.ComboBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(104, 116)
    Me.ComboBox1.Name = "ComboBox1"
    Me.ComboBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(121, 21)
    Me.ComboBox1.TabIndex = 0
    Me.ComboBox1.Text = "Select from..."
```

Any Help or Direction would be great!
Thank You

Comment: [ComboBox.DataSource](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.datasource), [ComboBox.DisplayMemeber](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember), [ComboBox.ValueMemeber](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember). The DataSource can be a List, a Dictionary (`.ToList()`), a DataTable (`DataView`), a collection of custom class objects that contain the data to present in the ListControl. Each `Item` of the ListControl will be a member of your collection of objects.

Comment: You can specify which property in the collection of items will provide the data to display, setting `[ComboBox].DisplayMember = "ThePropertyName"`, and a property that provides a value, using `[ComboBox].ValueMember = "AnotherPropertyName"`. The `GetItemsText()` method returns the value of the property used as `DisplayMember`. Using a `Dictionary(Of String, Double)` as DataSource, for example, you can set: `comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Key" comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value" comboBox1.DataSource = [TheDictionary].ToList()`. BTW, do not touch the code in the `InitializeComponent()` method.

Comment: `Me.ComboBox1.Text = "Select from..."`.  I always wonder why people think that users need instruction on how to use a drop-down but can figure out how to use other controls on their own.  How are people going to know how to use a `TextBox` if you don't put "Type here..." into it?

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This is all new to me so, there will be a lot of trial and error, and research to figure out how to implement this into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other Devs said before, here you have a little example:

```
 'Your ComboBox Custom Item
 Public Class MyComboItem
    Private _Text As String
    Private _IntValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal mText As String, ByVal mValue As Integer)
        Me._Text = mText
        Me._IntValue = mValue
    End Sub 'New

    Public ReadOnly Property Text() As String
        Get
            Return _Text
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Value() As Integer
        Get
            Return _IntValue
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And here the usage:

```
        Dim fabricsArray As ArrayList = New ArrayList
        fabricsArray.Add(New MyComboItem("Carbon Fiber Twill", 2))
        fabricsArray.Add(New MyComboItem("Carbon Fiber Plain", 5))

        ComboBox1.DataSource = fabricsArray
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text"

        AddHandler ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged, Sub(senderObj As Object, eObj As EventArgs)
                                                       MsgBox(CType(ComboBox1.Items(ComboBox1.SelectedIndex), MyComboItem).Value)
                                                   End Sub
```